# How should I protect a web service against a browser's automatic background fetching?

Tags: django, google-chrome

I have a boring corporate website built in Django that does boring corporate things.

One component of this website is a background task to FTP some boring corporate things from one place to another. When you go to the appropriate URL, you can trigger a change in the background worker (namely: start, stop, check status).

The problem here is that, when I'm working in Chrome, sometimes typing part of a similar URL causes Chrome to send a GET request (or something that Django interprets as a GET request) to fetch the page that's part of the web service to send instructions to the background worker. In other words, without hitting Enter on the keyboard, the worker can be started or stopped.

The problem *isn't* Chrome's settings. Yes, I could change the settings and fix the problem for myself, but that won't prevent someone in the future from typing a URL and triggering the same behavior.

What I would really like is a way to distinguish these prefetch calls from regular user-initiated calls, but that doesn't seem possible. I might be wrong, though. Barring that, I would like a setup that tells Chrome not to fetch that page. Unfortunately, there's a laundry list of boring corporate cruft that prevents some of the easy ways out.

The web service call must be possible for both a computer that treats cookies like trash and a non-techy human at a browser who doesn't have a link on the website itself to click through. The web service can't be moved to a separate subdomain. The web service can't be protected by Django's or any similarly localized authentication. I would like for the call to still be as simple as typing a URL into the browser's address bar, but that's not a requirement for anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What chrome is doing is considered "valid" because in the HTTP protocol, GET requests are assumed not cause side effects (something that occurs besides the returning of the response, such as triggering a background worker). They should be considered to be used only for retrieving data. In other words, [GET requests should be "Safe and Idempotent"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-9.1). By having a GET request do more than just retrieve data (such as cause a background worker to start), you are going against the HTTP protocol.

Change your site to only trigger these "changes" on POST requests. Google chrome will not make arbitrary POST requests like it does GET requests. You can still use GET requests for users to retrieve an HTML page that might have forms that allow them to do a POST to activate your various services, but the resource (URL) that the user hits to do something that has a "side effect" should only do that side effect if the user POSTs to the resource.

In a Django view, you can detect if a request is a GET, POST or other method by using [`request.method`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.method) attribute:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    do_something()
```